# Uniform recombination of binary representation of two integers

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba

I am in need for a fast implementation of the following problem, preferably as a numba function. I take two random integers `a`&`b` from a list called `integerlist` and consider their binary representation of length `l`, e.g.
`a=10->1010`, `b=6->0110`. Afterwards I perform a uniform crossover between both binary representations and the integer value of the resulting binary number is saved at a random position in the `integerlist`. Uniform recombination means that each entry of the binary representation of integer `c` is either taken from the binary representation entry of `a` or `b` with equal probability, e.g.

```
a=10->1010
b=6 ->0110
      1110 ->c=14
```

To do so I came up with the following code which is not very fast. At the moment I am trying to get a numba version of this function but wasn't successful so far. Could you help?

```
def recombination(integerlist, l):
    N = len(integerlist)
    for x1 in range(N):
        a = integerlist[random.randint(0, N-1)]
        b = integerlist[random.randint(0, N-1)]
        binary_a = list(map(int, numpy.binary_repr(a, width=l)))
        binary_b = list(map(int, numpy.binary_repr(b, width=l)))
        binary_c = [0]*l
        for x2 in range(l):
            if random.random() <= 0.5:
                binary_c[x2] = binary_a[x2]
            else:
                binary_c[x2] = binary_b[x2]
        c = 0
        for bit in binary_c:
            c = (c << 1) | bit
        integerlist[random.randint(0, N-1)] = c
```

**Edit:** If I replace `list(map(int, numpy.binary_repr(a, width=l)))` with the following function

```
@nb.njit
def dec_to_binary_fct(a, l):
    bin_temp = []
    for i in range(l):
        i = l-i-1
        k = a >> i
        if (k & 1):
            bin_temp.append(1)
        else:
            bin_temp.append(0)
    return bin_temp
```

I can put `@nb.njit` in front of `def recombination(integerlist, l):` which already increase the performance quite a bit. I am still curious if the performance could be increased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way of calculating the crossover which I'm pretty sure is faster:

```
def xover(a, b):
    l = max(a.bit_length(), b.bit_length())
    return a^((a^b)&random.randint(0, (1<<l)-1))
```

Explanation:

- we first use bitwise exclusive or to find the bits that differ (for the other bits it doesn't matter where we take them from, so we may as well take all of them from a)
- then we use bitwise and with a random mask to delete on average half of them
- and finally use bitwise exclusive or again to flip the remaining bits in a (we know that at these positions a flipped is b)

Comment: That is a really nice idea but a bit unfornutate that it only applies to `l<32`. At least `l<64` would be nice.

Comment: @HighwayJohn just change the random range. The upper limit must be a power of two (minus one if you choose to use `random` instead of `np.random`). If you are going beyond 64, I think the `random` module is definitely the better choice if `np.random` works at all. If you are using exactly 64 with numpy make sure to use `uint64`

Comment: Wow, perfect, thanks a lot! I probably can figure it out but max() seems to be not supported in numba. Do you know by chance a workaround?

Comment: @HighwayJohn Not really, no. Maybe and I'm really just guessing it will accept a single sequence argument instead of two individual arguments?

Comment: If you know that all your numbers are smaller than some number `X` then use a fixed `l` . Since you are only computing it once you can use expensive functions like `log2(X)` for that.

Comment: Okay, thanks! It increased the performance of the code by quite a bit :)